# Probability that 3 of 4 people are on 4 of 12 seats by allowing occupancy of seat for more than on person.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I asked a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/869818/probability-that-exactly-2-of-3-objects-are-in-1-of-3-baskets-with-sizes-5-8-2) which is as follows:

Four (identical) persons enter a train (section A has 4 seats, section B has 8 seats). What is the probability that exactly (not more or less) 3 persons sit in section A? (all seats have the same probability)

This problem is known as one of the urn problems and follows the hypergeometric distribution ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution)). The probability can be calculated this way:

$$\frac{\binom{R}{r}\binom{N-R}{n-r}}{\binom{N}{n}}=\frac{\binom{4}{3}\binom{8}{1}}{\binom{12}{4}}$$

I now would like to calculate the probability that exactly (not more or less) 3 persons sit in section A IF MAXIMUM 2 PEOPLE CAN SIT ON ONE SEAT AT THE SAME TIME?

What I could find out so far is that if one selects r of the n seats and allowing that a seat can be chosen again, the number of possibilities can be calculated by

$$\binom{n+r-1}{r}$$

Unfortunately one can't specify a maximum.

Answer (score 0):

It's really the same as having twice as many seats in each section with the original maximum of one person per seat. So the answer would be:

$$\frac{\binom{2R}{r}\binom{2N-2R}{n-r}}{\binom{2N}{n}}=\frac{\binom{8}{3}\binom{16}{1}}{\binom{24}{4}}$$

where, as before,
\begin{eqnarray*}
N &=& \mbox{total seats in train} \\
R &=& \mbox{total seats in Section A} \\
n &=& \mbox{number of persons} \\
r &=& \mbox{number of seats chosen in Section A.}
\end{eqnarray*}